# 301 redirect after url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I did some htaccess URL rewrite. To keep my google ranking I must redirect the old URL to the new one; the problem is the old URL still 'exist' and I'm not sure how to do the redirect. This is an example:

old url: mypage.php?id=myId
which now is rewritten as: mypage-myId.html

this is the htaccess directive

RewriteRule ^mypage-([A-Za-z0-9_-]+).html$ mypage.php?id=$1 [L]

now I want to 301 redirect all the old url (mypage.php?id=myIds) to the new url (mypage-myIds.html).
I tried this at the top of my htaccess file:
redirect 301 `mypage.php?id=1` to `mypage-1.html`
but nothing happens, the page stays on `mypage.php?id=1`.

What's wrong with this? I found another post about this problem
[url rewrite & redirect question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807356/url-rewrite-redirect-question)
but the solution wasn't that clear to me.

Thanks in advance
Vittorio

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$  # fetch ID
RewriteRule ^mypage\.php$ http://domain.com/mypage-%1.html [R=301,L]  # redirect old URL to new

RewriteRule ^mypage-([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\.html$ mypage.php?id=$1 [L]  # rewrite
```

Comment: hi..does not work..the browser sends an  Errore 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS):

Comment: I solved using a php redirect and changing the name of the query string parameter.